# What is the CASE logic when building a MicroStrategy Dashboard?

Tags: logic, case, dashboard, microstrategy

I am in the process of building a live dashboard, however, I need to perform a few 'IF, THEN, ELSE' (CASE) functions...  The current logic I've found is below.

```
ApplySimple(“Case when [Field Header Name]='CONDITION1’ then 'condition1 example' end”,String1)
```

What I've found online is a little misleading and wondering if anyone can assist.

Field Name is called 'Group'
There are certain 'Group' names that I want to put in a certain category using the CASE logic.

```
CASE
WHEN Group='CONDITION1'
THEN 'condition1 example'
END
```

Thank you so much

p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ApplySimple(“Case when #0='CONDITION1’ then 'condition1 example' end”,[Field Header Name])
```

See link below

http://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Architect/TN3905-How-to-use-pass-through-expression-ApplySimple-in/ta-p/165536

Comment: Thank you Tristan.  I'm curious, what does the #0 do or represent?

Comment: #0 represents "Field Header name"i.e the first column you are trying to pass through, you can add further conditions like  ApplySimple(“Case when #0='CONDITION1’ then 'condition1 example' when #1= 'Condition2' then 'Condition2' end”,[Field Header Name], [Filed Header Name2] ).. Here #1 represents [Filed Header Name2] ...